# lilypond bug with octave change/whole note

Tags: notation, lilypond

I'm using lilypond with Frescobaldi to notate a piano score.  My time signature is 4/4, and I just did a clef change, changing the bottom clef to treble for a few notes.  I returned the clef to bass, and then inserted an a1,, into the next measure.  It kicked back an error message and couldn't engrave; however, when I

1) change the a1,, to a2,,

or

2) change the a1,, to plain a1

it engraves just fine (the first example correctly engraves it as a half note, the second engraves it as an A natural two octaves above the pitch I desire.

But try as I might, it simply refuses to engrave the whole note duration at that octave.  I'm in \relative mode; I'm quite sure there's a workaround using absolute, but this is frustrating. Is this a bug or am I missing something?  I', new to the program so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Please post a minimal complete (non-)working example so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `a,,1`, not `a1,,`.  Pitch first, duration afterwards. You cannot split the pitch by putting the duration in the middle.

Comment: Thanks lol, it makes sense that it was something simple I was missing. It was my third time using the program and I was returning to the project after a couple days’ wait.